# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 while archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I tried to archive my App and get this error: 
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

When I Build it everything went fine, also on real devices. While archiving this happens. Any Ideas how to fix ?

This is a part of the error:

```
0  swift                    0x000000010f79f3ad PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x000000010f79eb56 SignalHandler(int) + 790
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fffc82d5bba _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000000000040 _sigtramp + 936551584
4  swift                    0x000000010cae0de3 swift::CastOptimizer::optimizeUnconditionalCheckedCastAddrInst(swift::UnconditionalCheckedCastAddrInst*) + 1699
5  swift                    0x000000010cb69d4d processFunction(swift::SILFunction&, bool, unsigned int) + 1917
6  swift                    0x000000010cb70c9f (anonymous namespace)::ConstantPropagation::run() + 47
7  swift                    0x000000010caff89e swift::SILPassManager::runOneIteration() + 5166
8  swift                    0x000000010cb051f6 swift::runSILOptimizationPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 3462
9  swift                    0x000000010c7ac0e2 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 20114
10 swift                    0x000000010c7a52b3 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17859
11 swift                    0x000000010c7615cf main + 8239
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fffc80c8255 start + 1
13 libdyld.dylib            0x00000000000000ee start + 938704538
```

And at the end:

```
1.  While running pass #38147 SILFunctionTransform "Constant Propagation" on SILFunction "@_TTSg5VSC29UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKeyS_s8Hashable5UIKit_P__CSo8NSObjectS2_S0_10ObjectiveC_Ps9AnyObject____TFs17_dictionaryUpCastu2_Rxs8Hashable0_S_rFGVs10Dictionaryxq__GS0_q0_q1__".
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and deleting DerivedData?

Comment: @user6603599 yes I did didn't work

Comment: What about disabling Swift Compiler Optimization for Release?

Comment: @user6603599 okay, now im getting this error `error: .../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AWSSNS/AWSSNS.framework: No such file or directory`

Comment: Have a look at the frameworks; is AWSSNS.framework listed in red color?

Comment: @user6603599 yes I added it via cocoa pods

Comment: The reason for that the file is in red is that Xcode can't find it. Try running again `pod install` in Terminal in the project folder.

Comment: @user6603599 I did so but it didn't changed

Comment: Try commenting or removing the line with the pod in the Podfile and run `pod install` . Then, uncomment or add it again and run `pod install`. This will delete and re-add the pod.

Comment: It still wont work

Comment: But is it still in red color?

Comment: Yes they still are

Comment: In the file inspector of the framework click on the folder icon next to "Location" and locate the framework manually.

Comment: Perfect it worked! :) I just installed the pods once again

Comment: does disabling Swift Compiler Optimization for Release affect anything ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't affect anything, but if the error is present with it enabled you should disable it. What did help you? So I can write an answer.

Comment: I think I did something wrong at the delete devidet data part. I just got the file back from the bin. And then it worked

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer so that other people can solve their issues.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try disabling Swift Compiler Optimization for Release

Then if you get any errors for missing files:

In the file inspector of the file click on the folder icon next to "Location" and locate the file manually

Comment: Try disabling Swift Compiler Optimization for Release - to be more specific: In your target > Build Settings > Optimization Level > Release > No optimization [-Onone]

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I tested all solutions including disabling optimization in the build settings:

Build Settings > Optimization Level > Release > No optimization [-Onone]

I don't recommend the above solution since this will affect your entire app and your final binary won't be optimized.

Based on contact with technical team at Apple, There are multiple reasons that could lead to this error, however there's a known bug for archiving during optimization and you need to bypass it by finding the place that compiler is failing and add `@_optimize(none)` at the top of your function that's causing the issue.

This attribute will tell compiler to ignore the function for optimisation.

```
class MyNavigationController:UINavigationController {

    @_optimize(none)
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController?, context: AppContextProtocol) {
      // content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Build Settings -> Swift 3 @Objc inference. It most likely should be off.