# Xcode 11.4 - Archiving project - Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segmentation-fault

I Just updated Xcode to 11.4 and when archiving a project it shows me 'Segmentation Fault 11'

This project would archive with Xcode 11.3.1 but now it doesn't..

Anyone else ran into the same issue?

[image]

**Edit: April 15th 2020**

Apple just released Xcode 11.4.1

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42168123/2583679

Comment: @Tom thank you, however that doesn't fix it.. im pretty sure its an Apple bug

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have run into the same issue. Archiving uses the Release building configuration so I went through every compiler setting to work out which of the differences lead to these Segmentation faults.

In my case the problem disappears when I change the setting **Enable Testability** to **YES** for **Release**.

No I have no idea what the downsides to this are in the archive or release build, or indeed why this particular setting alleviates the problem, but at the end of the day, I have a project that has taken a year to get to this stage and I'm very keen to get this to internal beta testers so I am going to submit this through test flight and see how I go.

My feeling is this is definitely an Apple bug, as the compiler should not be Seg Faulting at all. The fact it compiles under the Debug configuration lends support to this. My project is so large that I don't know how to reproduce this to submit a bug, but I'll see if I can get some response on the Apple Forums.

Comment: Ran into the same problem in Xcode 11.4.1, changing this setting worked for me as well. The docs say this flag has to do with making private interfaces accessible, so maybe there is something there... When this setting is activated, the product will be built with options appropriate for running automated tests, such as making private interfaces accessible to the tests. This may result in tests running slower than they would without testability enabled.

Comment: this did not work for me, and project won't build for the debug and release. Xcode 11.4.1 did not help aswell, I am still getting Segmentation fault 11.

Comment: this did not work for me. I am trying to debut the project in Xcode 11.5. I also tried to disabling Swift Compiler Optimization for Release but not work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It worked for me, xcode12 and the errors were in the pods.

Comment: me to faced same problem in Xcode 13.0, but above tricks does not worked. im still no idea about the issue.

Answer (score 8):

For me helped to find the problem when I set in build settings the `SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE` to `wholemodule`. Then after compiling got a more specific error which led to class function which caused the error.
Afterward changed it back as it was.

Maybe it helps you also.

In my case, there was used ternary operator for init input param set.
Seems like Swift 5.2 don't support it anymore.

```
// Leads to error with Xcode 11.4
init(value: UIColor = Constants.staticBoolean ? .white : .green)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! you made my day!!

Comment: That fixes my build time error too. A ternary operator in default param is the culprit. Hope Apple fixes the bug soon.

Comment: I'm not reproducing with Swift master branch https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/. So maybe already fixed.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had an error with Eureka pod

```
Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'Eureka' from project 'Pods')
```

In Pods file I've provided latest version:

```
pod 'Eureka', '~> 5.2.1'
```

Also set `SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE` set to `wholemodule`.

Answer (score 2):

Like other responders, there was a SwiftUI issue buried in the error messages here (using Xcode 11.4).  In my case, use of `.embedInScrollView()` was causing the build error.  Disabling those calls fixed it.  As a workaround, I put `.embedInScrollView()` into a ViewModifier, like this:

```
public struct WrapInScrollView: ViewModifier {
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .embedInScrollView()
    }

    public init() {}
}
```

Then I use that modifier a bit like the original call, like this:

```
.modifier(WrapInScrollView())
```

This means you can still embed in a scrollView but the Seg 11 errors go away.

Answer (score 2):

I had two same name variables with @Published. Xcode 11.4.1 compiler couldn't detect 'two same variables'- instead it returned Segmentation fault 11.

```
@Published var isVirtualRacing = UserDefaults.isVirtualRacing {
  willSet {
  UserDefaults.isVirtualRacing = newValue
  }
}

@Published var isVirtualRacing = UserDefaults.isVirtualRacing {
willSet {
  UserDefaults.isVirtualRacing = newValue
  }
}
```

[image: you should read all the errors]

Comment: I had exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_name")` to `UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image_name")`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the error with Eureka

The only thing that fixed the error was the temporary solution of [WilsonGramer](https://github.com/WilsonGramer)

The solution is the next:

"I found a workaround for this by replacing [unowned self] in RowType.swift with [weak self] and force-unwrapping the self. This prevents the compiler from crashing in Xcode 11.4 — if you'd like to take a look you can use my fork: https://github.com/Wilsonator5000/Eureka/tree/fix/xcode11.4-unowned-self

Project maintainers, if this is a suitable fix please let me know and I'll open a pull request!" [WilsonGramer](https://github.com/WilsonGramer)

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple. Go to Xcode menu in : **Product** -> **Scheme** -> **Edit Scheme...**  Select **Build** on the left menu. And check **Build Options** - **Find Implicit Dependencies** should be turned ON. [Photo of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSWZy.png)

Answer (score 1):

For people who get this error because of the Eureka library, the Eureka project has a separate branch called **xcode12** that fixes this issue. It compiles on Xcode 12 without problems.

https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/tree/xcode12

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the *[Enable Testability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60894750/616982)* solution did not work for me.

A temporary workaround (until Apple will fix the Xcode 11.4 Swift compiler issue) is to turn the **Optimization Level** to "**No Optimization**" for Release, on the target that fails (`SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone";`). It works on our project, which is split into multiple frameworks. Just one need to be set to `-Onone`.

But the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html) asks to **not shipping your code with this flag**. It's for development, it performs minimal optimizations and preserves all debug info.

I think we have to wait :'(

Comment: this did not work for me, and project won't build for the debug and release. Xcode 11.4.1 did not help aswell, I am still getting Segmentation fault 11.

Comment: It was an issue with a bad Type inference and a Generic. Research via compilation dichotomy resolved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I have two variables (`AnyCancellable` and a `@Published`) with the same name in my `ObservableObject` object. That was run in xCode 11.5

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was in one of the Remote Swift Package (Xcode 12). I just dragged the package to the project and the problem solved.