# Xcode 11.5 - segmentation fault 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My live project is working fine in XCode 11.3.1
After updated to Xcode 11.5 lot of swift files show error as "segmentation fault 11" but doesn't show exact error ... I am confused

Segmentation fault: 11 (in target '#####' from project '#####')

Updated to XCode 11.6 beta also doesn't works

NOTE: App working in Xcode 11.3.1 .........

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865057/xcode-11-4-archiving-project-segmentation-fault-11#comment108028458_60929029

Comment: A segfault in Swift is always the result of a compiler bug. There's not much you can do against it, simply rebuild your project and if that doesn't help, clean derived data and then rebuild, that should resolve the issue. I've seen an increased number of segfaults with Xcode 11.4 and 11.5 as well.